# Xcode include lib error Typedef redefinition with different types

Tags: xcode, include, pjsip

Here is the header search paths:

```
"$(SRCROOT)/../pjsip/third_party/lib"
/pjsip/third_party/lib

"$(SRCROOT)/../pjsip/pjlib/lib"

"$(SRCROOT)/../pjsip/pjlib-util/lib"

"$(SRCROOT)/../pjsip/pjmedia/lib"

"$(SRCROOT)/../pjsip/pjnath/lib"

"$(SRCROOT)/../pjsip/pjsip/lib"
```

It can find the header and libs, but this error occurs at `#include <pjsip.h>`:

```
Typedef redefinition with different types ('int' vs '__darwin_socklen_t' (aka 'unsigned int'))
```

Answer (score 1):

First I think this can be identified as a compile error. Duplicate symbol define `int` and `__darwin_socklen_t`, surely it's strange.

It's better to create new empty project and add the search path and #include step by step to see which point cause the problem.

If you use objc, try renaming all '.m' files to '.mm'.

Comment: great,i think no duplicate symbol,but rename .m to .mm work great,thanks.